# Moving image on click using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image at the side of my website, i want to hide most of the image until the user clicks on it (its for a newsletter signup), what would be the best way of going about this?

I just need a section of this image showing, then whenever the user clicks on it the whole image pops out.  I know i can use CSS to move the image about, what would the best javascript function to use instead of using the change image function as im only moving the image not changing it?

Example site where this is demonstrated: http://www.plus.de/

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: Check this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741303/jquery-move-div-left-on-click-then-right-on-click][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741303/jquery-move-div-left-on-click-then-right-on-click

Comment: You should provide more details if you want people to help you.

Comment: What @JorisLindhout said + you can't use an image to display a signup form, but you can use something like a div with a background image and a form inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/d75AV/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">
  <span class="text">OPEN</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#overflow {
  background: rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide {
  background: #0296cc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: -270px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.text {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 80px 0 0 196px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $('.slide').click(function() {

    var overflow = ('<div id="overflow"><div>');

    $(this).stop().animate({ left: '0' }, 650);

    if($('#overflow').length < 1) {
       $('body').append(overflow);
    }

    $('#overflow').fadeIn('slow');

    $('#overflow').click(function() {

      $(this).fadeOut('slow') 
      $('.slide').stop().animate({ left: '-270px' }, 650);

    });

    // Prevents window scroll when overflow is visible
    $('#overflow').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
      var scrollTo = null;

      if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
          scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
      }
      else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
         scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
      }

      if (scrollTo) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
      }
    });    


  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[BASIC DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ozagoHA/1/edit)**

```
  <div id="gallery">

    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="" />

    <div id="tabs">
      <div>Tab 1</div>
      <div>Tab 2</div>
      <div>Tab 3</div>
      <div>Tab 4</div>     
    </div>

  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#gallery{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background:#eee;
}
#gallery > img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  margin:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#gallery > img + img{
  display:none;
}

#tabs{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0;
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
}

#tabs > div{
  cursor:pointer;
  height:49px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#tabs > div').click(function(){

  var i = $(this).index();
  $('#gallery > img').stop().fadeTo(300,0).eq(i).fadeTo(500,1);

});
```

Comment: he didnt ask for an image gallery.